# Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I have been trying to run my ruby application on the server recently and I keep coming across this error:

```
Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I am running Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3p392. Until now I have not had any problems when accessing the server, and this is the first time I have come across this error.

I have tried looking around for answers, but as I am relatively new to ruby and rails I couldn't find an answer that was simple to understand.

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# STANDARD SET OF GEMS, SEE BOTTOM OF FILE FOR A LIST OF OTHER USEFUL GEMS

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'retina_tag'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'contact_form'
gem 'draper'
gem 'pony'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'libv8','~> 3.11.8'

gem "therubyracer"
gem 'less-rails'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" 
gem "font-awesome-rails", "~> 3.0.2.0"
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'actionpack'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'railties'
gem 'less'
gem "mailtrap", "~> 0.2.1"


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'

  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'thin'

  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'

  ## GUARD -- used to automatically run commands
  # gem 'guard'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
  # gem 'growl'
  # gem 'guard-rspec'
  # gem 'guard-yard'
  # gem 'redcarpet' 
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'metric_fu'

  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

  # The use of 'shoulda' and 'shoulda-context' will break testing in Ruby 1.9.3
  # so we explicitly use 'shoulda-matchers' only for testing purposes
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'

  # gem 'capybara-webkit'
end
```

`Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    active_utils (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activemerchant (1.32.1)
      active_utils (>= 1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
      i18n
      json (>= 1.5.1)
      money
      nokogiri
    activemodel (3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
    activesupport (3.2.12)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.4)
    airbrake (3.1.11)
      activesupport
      builder
      json
    arel (3.0.2)
    arrayfields (4.7.4)
    awesome_print (1.1.0)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bluff (0.1.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.9)
    cane (2.5.2)
      parallel
    capistrano (2.15.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
      capistrano (>= 1.0.0)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    chronic (0.9.1)
    churn (0.0.28)
      chronic (>= 0.2.3)
      hirb
      json_pure
      main
      ruby_parser (~> 3.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.1)
    code_analyzer (0.3.1)
      sexp_processor
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    colored (1.2)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    commonjs (0.2.6)
    contact_form (0.0.2)
      i18n
      jquery-rails
      mail
      rails (~> 3.2.8)
    cucumber (1.3.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    cucumber-rails (1.3.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (0.9.1)
    debugger (1.5.0)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.2.0)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.0)
    devise (2.2.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    draper (1.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      request_store (~> 1.0.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    event-calendar (2.3.3)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fattr (2.2.1)
    flay (2.0.1)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.0)
    flog (3.2.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.1, > 3.1.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.0)
    font-awesome-rails (3.0.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    gherkin (2.12.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    googlecharts (1.6.8)
    haml (4.0.2)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      haml (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
    highline (1.6.18)
    hike (1.2.2)
    hirb (0.7.1)
    hoe (3.6.0)
      rake (>= 0.8, < 11.0)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    japgolly-Saikuro (1.1.1.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.0.2)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    json_pure (1.7.7)
    launchy (2.2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    less (2.3.2)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.6)
    less-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.3.1)
    letter_opener (1.1.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2.0)
    libv8 (3.11.8.17)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mailtrap (0.2.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.8)
      hoe (>= 1.3.0)
      trollop (>= 1.7)
    main (5.2.0)
      arrayfields (>= 4.7.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.2)
      fattr (>= 2.2.0)
      map (>= 5.1.0)
    map (6.2.0)
    method_source (0.8.1)
    metric_fu (4.1.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.0.0)
      arrayfields (= 4.7.4)
      bluff
      cane (= 2.5.2)
      churn (= 0.0.28)
      coderay
      fattr (= 2.2.1)
      flay (= 2.0.1)
      flog (= 3.2.2)
      googlecharts
      japgolly-Saikuro (>= 1.1.1.0)
      map (= 6.2.0)
      metric_fu-roodi (>= 2.2.1)
      parallel (= 0.6.2)
      rails_best_practices (= 1.13.2)
      redcard
      reek (= 1.3.1)
      ruby2ruby (= 2.0.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.0, >= 3.1.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.0)
    metric_fu-roodi (2.2.1)
      ruby_parser
    mime-types (1.23)
    money (5.1.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6.0)
    multi_json (1.7.2)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-scp (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.6.7)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    nokogiri (1.5.9)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    parallel (0.6.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pony (1.4)
      mail (> 2.0)
    progressbar (0.20.0)
    pry (0.9.12.1)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-rails (0.2.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.12)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activerecord (= 3.2.12)
      activeresource (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.12)
    rails_best_practices (1.13.2)
      activesupport
      awesome_print
      code_analyzer
      colored
      erubis
      i18n
      progressbar
    railties (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcard (1.1.0)
    reek (1.3.1)
      ruby2ruby (~> 2.0.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.1.1)
      sexp_processor
    ref (1.0.4)
    request_store (1.0.5)
    retina_tag (1.1.9)
      jquery-rails
      rails (>= 3.1)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    ruby2ruby (2.0.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.0)
    ruby_parser (3.1.3)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.1)
    sass (3.2.8)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sexp_processor (4.2.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simplecov (0.7.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.7.1)
    simplecov-html (0.7.1)
    slop (3.4.4)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    trollop (2.0)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      execjs
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.0.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.4)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  actionpack
  activemerchant
  activesupport
  airbrake
  bootstrap-will_paginate
  cancan
  capistrano
  capistrano-ext
  capybara
  coffee-rails
  contact_form
  cucumber
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  debugger
  devise
  draper
  event-calendar
  factory_girl_rails
  font-awesome-rails (~> 3.0.2.0)
  haml-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  launchy
  less
  less-rails
  letter_opener
  libv8 (~> 3.11.8)
  mailtrap (~> 0.2.1)
  metric_fu
  mysql2
  pony
  pry-rails
  rails (= 3.2.12)
  railties
  retina_tag
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  shoulda-matchers
  simplecov
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  thin
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier
  will_paginate
```

Cheers

Comment: are you using rvm may be rvm ruby version or gemset go scroweded up

Comment: I am not using rvm, and haven't used it at all in this project

Comment: what does gem list rake show?

Comment: 'code' 
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (10.0.4, 10.0.3)
'code'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sometimes we didn't get the response from http://rubygems.org/. So it will show the given error.

You can use following ways for fixing this issue

- Try again for gem install using `gem install rack` command and run `bundle update rake` for updating your Gemfile.lock file.
- Delete the Gemfile.lock and again bundle install it.

Comment: is there some specific reason for it?

Comment: @JAF yes, you are right. Try to avoid `sudo` while using `bundle install`.  But some times you have to use `sudo` while installing specific gem out side the project.

Answer (score 14):

Try to delete `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install`

Answer (score -4):

If you have .rvmrc(which specifies the ruby and gemset is going to be used) in your app directory, just come out of the app dir, then again go into app dir.

In you add dir just give command,

```
cd .
```

or

```
cd
cd appdir
```

It will reload the all the gems required for your app.