# Ruby on Rails - Could not find xpath-2.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, rspec

Trying to run 'rails g rspec:install' and keep running into error:

```
Could not find xpath-2.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I am running 
ruby 2.2.0p0
rails 4.2.0

I have tried looking around for answers, but as I am relatively new to ruby and rails I couldn't find an answer. I have tried some of the following suggestions from other threads to no avail:

> sometimes we doesn’t get response from http://rubygems.org/ so it will shows error again try gem install rake to install latest version (10.0.4) of rake, and next bundle update rake to update the Gemfile.lock
>
> ([Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189338/could-not-find-rake-10-0-4-in-any-of-the-sources-bundlergemnotfound))

and

> Try to delete Gemfile.lock and bundle install
>
> ([Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189338/could-not-find-rake-10-0-4-in-any-of-the-sources-bundlergemnotfound))

no luck with any of those options.

GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '~>2.1.0'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
 GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.5.1)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.0)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.3.0)
    globalid (0.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.6)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    loofah (2.0.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.5.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    rack (1.6.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.2)
      rspec-expectations (>= 2.99.0.beta1)
    rspec-core (2.99.2)
    rspec-expectations (2.99.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.99.3)
    rspec-rails (2.99.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-collection_matchers
      rspec-core (~> 2.99.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.99.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.99.0)
    sass (3.4.11)
    sass-rails (5.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.2.0)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.0.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (~> 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  capybara (~> 2.1.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  rspec-rails (~> 2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

RubyGems Environment:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /volumes/ALEX/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /volumes/ALEX/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/alexmattson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/
```

which gem

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

which bundle

```
/usr/bin/bundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had a bad install of rbenv. After a reinstall it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the hang up would be as it's listed as a dependency of Capybara, but have you tried:

`gem install xpath -v '2.0.0'`

If that succeeds, rerun your bundle install.

Edit:

It looks like you're trying to use RBENV, but your gems are installing to your system version of Ruby. First, you should never have to use `sudo` on a `gem install` using RVM or RBENV.

Taken from the RBENV install documentation: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

It looks like step 3 might have been skipped, so verify by running from step 4:

```
type rbenv
#=> "rbenv is a function"
```

If this fails, you'll need to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your shell (.bash_profile, .bashrc or .zshrc depending on what OS and shell you're running).

Make sure to restart your terminal for any shell changes to take effect.

Run `rbenv rehash` then you should get something like this when you run which gem again:

```
which gem
#=> /Users/your-user-name/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

If this works, run `gem install bundle`, cd into your project directory and `bundle install` should work.

Comment: The gem install works but no luck after the rerun of bundle install.

Comment: What do you get when you run:

`which gem` and
`which bundle`

Comment: I added it to the end of the post. Also Im sure this is part of the problem is that when I do a gem install its giving me the following error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

I use sudo to get around it but I don't think you should need to do sudo for any gem install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, new version of RudyOnRails has some conflicts with Spring. Just try type in console `spring stop` and rerun `rails generate rspec:install`

Find out more info in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/996