# Correcting Bundle permissions after executing sudo bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

After running `sudo bundle install` I can't execute any command without the prefix sudo. For example if I want to generate a migration

```
 rails generate migration AddLastNameToCandidates last_name:string
```

it throws an error

```
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

however, if I run

```
 sudo rails generate migration AddLastNameToCandidates last_name:string
```

the migration gets generated successfully.

How can I revert this action and run commands such as `bundle install` without having to execute it as sudo?

Comment: Use Ruby environment as  https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: I read a little bit about that. But it just only helps with mantaining the same ruby version or with the gems as well?...

Comment: Yes, after setup type gem environment in shell to see gem path: e.g. GEM PATHS:
     - ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0

Comment: my rails is installed over rvm...is it the same? can't I do the same with rvm??

Comment: First remove RVM from your system because it is incompatible with rbenv. Remove with $ rvm implode, and then setup.  How-to https://reinteractive.net/posts/12-moving-from-rvm-to-rbenv

Comment: which one do you think it's better and why?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I kept trying and it was because every gem was under sudo domain indeed. I found the solution in this post

[Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189338/could-not-find-rake-10-0-4-in-any-of-the-sources-bundlergemnotfound)

```
Sometimes we don’t get response from http://rubygems.org/. So it will show the given error.

You can use following ways for fixing this issue

    Try again for gem install using gem install rack command and run bundle update rake for updating your Gemfile.lock file.
    Delete the Gemfile.lock and again bundle install it.
```

Now every command run perfectly without the sudo prefix